# How do i prevent pry/irb from outputting my content automatically?

Tags: irb, pry

For example,

```
[36] pry(main)> questions = Question.all
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    Question
  embedded: false>
```

I don't want it to output the Criteria, I just want to execute that statement w/o output.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a nil value:

```
>> questions = Question.all;p
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append at the end a semicolon

```
>> questions = Question.all;
```